# How to validate formfield

Tags: flutter

Am a newbie though. I followed a tutorial for my code below which is a register form. How can i validate each input field since it's just one widget which is reused for the entire input field.

............................................................................................................................................................

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterlogindesign/utils/color.dart';
import 'package:flutterlogindesign/widgets/btn_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutterlogindesign/widgets/herder_container.dart';

class RegPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegPageState createState() => _RegPageState();
}

class _RegPageState extends State<RegPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            HeaderContainer("Register"),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 30),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _textInput(hint: "Fullname", icon: Icons.person),
                    _textInput(hint: "Email", icon: Icons.email),
                    _textInput(hint: "Phone Number", icon: Icons.call),
                    _textInput(hint: "Password", icon: Icons.vpn_key),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Center(
                        child: ButtonWidget(
                          btnText: "REGISTER",
                          onClick: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "Already a member ? ",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "Login",
                            style: TextStyle(color: orangeColors)),
                      ]),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _textInput({controller, hint, icon}) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: hint,
            prefixIcon: Icon(icon),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Form** Widget like the following

```
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool autoValidate = false;
   String  phone;


 child:Form( key: _formKey,
      autovalidateMode: autoValidate ? AutovalidateMode.always : AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                   child: Column(
                           children: [
                                   AppTextFormField(
                                        initialValue: phone,
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          phone = value;
                                        },
                                        validator: (value) {
                                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                                            return 'Enter Phone number';
                                          }  
                                        },
                                    
                                      ),
                                      PrimaryButton(
                                        text: 'Go',
                                        onTap: () {
                                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                            _formKey.currentState.save();
                                            
                                          } else {
                                            autoValidate = true;
                                          }
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                              ),
```

Comment: if that solved your question , upvote and mark question as answered

Comment: I can't upvote i need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote